# But it is summer!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, internationalization

Stack Exchange is used world-wide. But in December - Winter is only on the northern part of the world.

Where I live for instance, in Argentina, it is hot, there is no snow or freezing. And, believe it or not, not everyone celebrates christmas or Hanukkah either.

Winterbash is fun - but next time could we make it fit more to a world-wide audience?

Comment: There is a disclaimer at the bottom of the [Winter Bash post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/?cb=1), it is tradition to call it Winter Bash.

Comment: Calling it just bash would be fun.

Comment: Winter Bash is awesome. Bash sounds like 'Bourne-Again Shell'.

Comment: @bluefeet: Who can argue with tradition?

Comment: WinmerBash. SumterBash. WinsumBash. SumwinBash. Or just Bash.

Comment: Looks like your weather's broken there, sir.

Comment: I've always been partial to HATFIGHT

Comment: We have Winter Bash now, will we have Winter Zsh and Winter SSH? :P

Answer (score 32):

Quoting the [Winter Bash 2014 announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/) from the blog:

> Before signing off, I apologize to our [Southern Hemisphere friends](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2288/o-que-voc%C3%AAs-t%C3%AAm-na-cabe%C3%A7a) for the name. I wanted to go with something season-neutral like HAT ATTACK or December Fling, but tradition ruled the day. Just remember: while you are sipping refreshing drinks and enjoying the sunshine, it’s [cold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuCO7Kq744U), wet, and dark up here.

So, yes, the devs are perfectly aware that it is summer in your neck of the woods. No, the name won't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps 'solstice bash' would avoid some of the other prejudices / assumptions / traditions /cultural impositions etc

but i am not pushing for any change, just reflecting on my own question at [What percent of SE users are in 'winter' during this 'winter bash'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319858/what-percent-of-se-users-are-in-winter-during-this-winter-bash) and trying to figure what if any symbolism might avoid some of the common 'traps' around such namings.

(Edited to correct from Equinox to Solstice per regettman's comment)

Answer (score -4):

I suggest the name to be changed to **Christmas-Hats** for next year.

We can keep "Winter Bash" as a second name and in the tags (and [christmas-hats] as a synonym).

Other suggestions (for the PC sensitive :)

- **New-Year-Hats** (I guess that wouldn't be totally PC either, the New Year is not celebrated on Jan 1 everywhere)
- **Hat-Dash** (the really ancient name)

or just:

- **Hats !!**

Comment: I don't think so but if it is changed, then please without the typo ...

Comment: @rene hey, check my name ;)

Comment: That's even more inconsiderate than "winter".

Comment: @Ghanima how so?

Comment: Considering the number of people who do not follow christianity and related public holidays?

Comment: I don't follow Christianity either.

Comment: .. but the related public holidays ;)

Comment: @Ghanima so you are saying that some people don't mind if  they celebrate Hats which just "happen" to be the same time as Christmas and (some countries') New Year season but they would be offended if the Hats celebration name was making the relation obvious?  Because the choice of 19-Dec to Jan-3 is not coincidence, I assure you.