# What percent of SE users are in 'winter' during this 'winter bash'?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, geography

Curiosity prompted by being a minority that lives in the Southern hemisphere. Are we forgotten, overlooked, ignored or simply hated by those in the temperate latitudes of the North who would actually consider 'now' to be winter ;-)

Comment: Is there a "neither of the above" option? Basically we didn't feel a need for a second Winter Bash, so you only get one

Comment: I live in King's Landing and there are Long winters there. I (Tyrion Lannister) was born in a short winter which lasted for three years. Winter came! So, you're not ignored living in other side.

Comment: @Nog Something I noticed: Nog Shine...Shog Nine (Shog9); intentional?

Comment: @Watchthisspace [I am his good friend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/357396).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245407/204841

Comment: thank you for that link Modus. I should have searched harder/more/a bit before posting

Comment: but as an ex- (no you can never be an ex-) Geographer, there was a genuine curiousity about this, not just in the N v S hemisphere context, but also the temperate v tropical (who - i may wrongly assume - don't necessarily consider this season to be 'winter' even if they are north of the equator)

Answer (score 7):

Trying to answer the specific answer on **what percent of SE users are in 'winter' during 'winter bash'**, I created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/944739/number-of-users-on-the-southern-hemisphere) that gets the number of users in the Southern Hemisphere (this is only for StackOverflow btw), and the current count is quite low, which is (at the time of writing this answer) **65212**, whilst the number of users that are NOT in the Southern Hemisphere are **2362818**, which means that the percentage is:

```
2.68579877514 %
```

Of course we are not taking into account the users that didn't list their countries in their profiles (which is quite high), but this is a good sample.

We can also run the same query on all the SE sites to get a better estimation.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you remove users in tropical regions who don't experience winter?

Comment: How is this a good sample if you can't verify that your basic assumption holds - that users are equally likely to withhold the information regardless of hemisphere?

Comment: @Nij sadly this is the only information we can rely on right now. But I still think it is a good sample.

Answer (score 7):

Luckily this year you can at least customize the homepage of https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/. Here's what I knitted in order to test the knitting editor while implementing it:

[image: Summer Bash 2018]

Comment: Man... your skills are totally wasted as programmer.

Answer (score 5):

The Developer Survey 2018 contains [geography information](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#geography), including monthly Stack Overflow visits:

[image]

I've added the countries lying (predominantly) on the Southern hemisphere and came up with a percentage of about **7%**, so for them 'Summer Bash' would be more appropriate. The other **93%** can still enjoy 'Winter Bash' with no lexical issues.

Comment: thank you - much harder though to figure out what portion of the 'north of the equator' population actually thinks of 'now' as 'winter'