# Winter Bash: "Member of The Hand" hat description

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Checking the description of the **Member of The Hand** hat, it says:

> post a question on answer on meta or on the main site that appears with the New Contributor indicatior and gets a score of 3

It looks to me that it contains a typo and it should be

> post a question **or** answer on meta ...

Am I correct, or do we have to post a "question on answer on meta ..."?

[image]

Comment: You're correct, it's a typo. Will fix.

Comment: @balpha Also "indicatior" should be spelt as "indicator" :)

Comment: @balpha I hope the awarding script is also correct as it looks like we both should have been awarded for [these answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319858/what-percent-of-se-users-are-in-winter-during-this-winter-bash/319872) :)

Comment: Ok, I think I am not understanding the challenge. I thought I had to answer a question with the "New Contributor" tag, even if I am not the new contributor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boht typoes are fixd now. Tanks!

Comment: Unaware user editing this to fix grammar in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Tanks to you, too!